# Structure containing dynamic data in non-procedural context for parameterized test class

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Below code in SV/UVM is producing VCS compile error shown after the code.

```
 typedef enum int {
  ABC,
  DEF,
  GHI,
 . . .
 } enum_t

class some_test #(type T=uvm_test) extends T;
 
 `uvm_component_param_utils(some_test#(T))

 bit assoc_array[3][enum_t];


 //bunch of tasks and functions here

 
 task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
   int index;
  
  //Below wait inside some fork-join and begin-end blocks
  //index calculated
  assoc_array[index].delete(); //Compiler OK here
  assoc_array[index][DEF] = 1; //Compiler OK here
 
  //some more forked threads

  wait(assoc_array[index].exists(ABC) && (assoc_array[index][ABC]==1)); //COMPILER ERROR
 endtask

endclass
```

Error is :

```
Error-[DTINPCIL] Dynamic type in non-procedural context
"wait ((this.assoc_array[index].exists(ABC) && (this.assoc_array[index][ABC] == 1))) ;"
  Argument: this.assoc_array[index]
  Structure containing dynamic data and/or used in dynamic arrays may not be 
  used in non-procedural context.
```

I do not understand why this is non-procedural context. Does it have anything to do with the test being a parameterized test? I am doing such "extends" to achieve multiple inheritance. I saw that in a blog by Tudor Timi titled "Fake it till you make it - Emulating multiple inheritance in System Verilog", though his example achieved something else and was definitely not on a parameterized test.

In some other test package, I have this piece of code as well:

```
typedef some_test #(some_basic_test) better_test;
```

Comment: I tried commenting both sides of &&. Left-side has the problem. Thanks for this tip. I could now proceed with this change, but I am not sure why exists() create a problem. And "non-procedural context"? Maybe there is something going on that I don't understand. I shall try to create a standalone example. The current one was just extracted from a big piece of code just for the sake of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your VCS compile error with a minimal code example on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Ghgd).  However, 3 other simulators do not produce compile errors.

I do not understand the error message.  The code uses `wait` inside a `task` called from an `initial` block, which seems like a procedural context to me.

I also tried on a more recent version of VCS that I have, and I get the same error.  You could contact Synopsys for help.

Here is the code I used:

```
module tb;

typedef enum int {
    ABC,
    DEF,
    GHI
} enum_t;

bit assoc_array[3][enum_t];
int index;

task runphase;
    assoc_array[index][DEF] = 1;
    wait(assoc_array[index].exists(ABC));
endtask

initial begin
    runphase();
end
endmodule
```